# Conditional formatting with VLOOKUP across sheets where value equals Yes

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, vlookup

I'm trying to highlight some cells based on a table in a different sheet.

I have a row of names in cells A1, A2, A3 etc on sheet 1.
On sheet 2 I have a table where it has a column (A) of the same names and another column (B) of the value "Yes" or "No".

I'm trying to get the names on sheet 1 to get highlighted if the value next to the equivalent name on sheet 2 has a yes next to it.

I tried this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A$1,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$B$26,2,0)="Yes"
```

But it doesn't like it for some reason. No error, just doesn't work.
Any ideas would be so helpful!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Try this in Conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine... :

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$B$26,2,0)="Yes"
```

And pull down to copy formatting only or change "Applies to" in the Conditional Formatting menu.

The problem was that you fixed the row, and not the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can't highlight cells based on a formula. (Technically you could create a rule with a hidden column, but still...).

Probably easier to do this with vba

```
Private Sub highlight_names()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, 1))
    Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = ws2.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr2, 1))

    For Each cell In rng
        For Each Name In rng2

            If (cell = Name And Name.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes") Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If

        Next Name
    Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: You can definitely do this with a formula. **Conditional Format** > **New Rule** > **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**

Comment: I'd rather not use VBA if I can help it. The person I'm making this sheet for may move the cells around and I don't quite understand how it references them. I'm pretty sure you can use formulas in conditional formatting as the urdearboy states but mine clearly doesn't work. Has anyone got a suggestion on a formula based approach or can someone explain how the vba above works? Thanks.

Comment: @udearboy Well I guess i should have worded myself a bit better. I meant to say it's not possible to highlight a cell via a direct formula (I did however mention that it is possible via a rule).  Though yeah, now that I think about it, it actually probably is in this case a better option to use conditional formatting.